# IP address field validation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to validate an IP address column in SharePoint 2010 with the following formula. I get an error telling me there's a syntax error without anymore details. Knowing it works in Excel; any idea what's wrong with this formula?

```
=AND((LEN(Address)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Address;".";"")))=3;ISNUMBER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Address;":";"");".";"")+0))
```

Comment: Have you tried to change parameter separator from semicolon to comma? In some installations comma is proper separator.

Comment: Yes, I've tried changing semicolons to a commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer reside in the fact that there are multiple limitations to **SharePoint** field validation by formula. Although it uses the same syntax as Excel, its far from being as versatile as **Excel** is. [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/examples-of-common-formulas-HA010379915.aspx?CTT=1#BM1)'s the well hidden reference that list available functions for field validation.

The problem in the previous question is that `SUBSTITUTE()` and `ISNUMBER()` aren't available.

A proper way to validate an IP address would be using a combination of `FIND()` and `MID()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working formula for SharePoint 2013 Online, where IP is the name of the column containing the IP address.  Note that there are 40 references to the column name, if you use a long column name to could reach the character limit on validation formulas (I originally had IP Address, which was 320 characters longer, also why I used FIND instead of SEARCH)

```
=IF(AND(AND(VALUE(LEFT([IP],FIND(".",[IP])))>=0,VALUE(LEFT([IP],FIND(".",[IP])))<256),AND(VALUE(MID([IP],FIND(".",[IP])+1,FIND(".",[IP],FIND(".",[IP])+1)-FIND(".",[IP])))>=0,VALUE(MID([IP],FIND(".",[IP])+1,FIND(".",[IP],FIND(".",[IP])+1)-FIND(".",[IP])))<256),AND(VALUE(MID([IP],FIND(".",[IP],FIND(".",[IP])+1)+1,FIND(".",[IP],FIND(".",[IP],FIND(".",[IP])+1)+1)-FIND(".",[IP],FIND(".",[IP])+1)))>=0,VALUE(MID([IP],FIND(".",[IP],FIND(".",[IP])+1)+1,FIND(".",[IP],FIND(".",[IP],FIND(".",[IP])+1)+1)-FIND(".",[IP],FIND(".",[IP])+1)))<256),AND(VALUE(RIGHT([IP],LEN([IP])-FIND(".",[IP],FIND(".",[IP],FIND(".",[IP])+1)+1)))>=0,VALUE(RIGHT([IP],LEN([IP])-FIND(".",[IP],FIND(".",[IP],FIND(".",[IP])+1)+1)))<256)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ISNUMBER function works, it is even mentioned in your link:

> To check if a column value or a part of it matches specific text, use the IF, FIND, SEARCH, and ISNUMBER functions.

I did need to add `+0` after my column name as mentioned [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30817/validate-if-the-entered-text-is-number).

**Edit:**
After further testing I have discovered that this solution allows for entries with spaces in so it is not ideal.